# Checking the version of Databricks Runtime in Azure

Tags: azure, version, azure-databricks

Is it possible to check the version of Databricks Runtime in Azure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Databricks Runtime is the set of core components that run on the clusters managed by Azure Databricks. It includes Apache Spark but also adds a number of components and updates that substantially improve the usability, performance, and security of big data analytics.

> You can choose from among many supported runtime versions when you
>   create a cluster.

[image]

> If you want to know the version of Databricks runtime in Azure after
>   creation:

Go to **Azure Data bricks portal** => **Clusters** => **Interactive Clusters** => here you can find the run time version.

[image]

For more details, refer "[Azure Databricks Runtime versions](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/release-notes/runtime/databricks-runtime-ver.html#runtime-components)".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 19):

In Scala:

```
dbutils.notebook.getContext.tags("sparkVersion")
```

In Python:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.sparkVersion")
```

Is giving you the Databricks runtime and Scala version back, e. g.: 5.0.x-scala2.11 .

Comment: Is it possible to get just the databricks runtime version. Instead of 5.0.x-scala2.11 just "5.0"

Answer (score 3):

```
print (spark.version)
```

worked for me

Comment: sorry ... this is not runtime version ... but that helped me at the time .. didn't know the reputation decreases after you remove an answer :)